# How to display div on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

This should be fairly simple, but I'm not that familiar with Javascript, so I'm getting stymied. I have this html:

```
<section class="main-container">
    <ul class="landing-list">
        <li class="main-headings">
            <strong>SERVICES</strong><i class="icon icon-angle-down"></i>
            <div class="main-blurb" id="blurb-1">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus assumenda, in a quaerat iusto. Reiciendis consequuntur doloribus, sed tenetur aspernatur sunt perspiciatis. Odit non eos laudantium fuga officiis quia eius!</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="main-headings">
            <strong>WHY CHOOSE PMDS?</strong><i class="icon icon-angle-down"></i>
            <div class="main-blurb" id="blurb-2">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo rerum totam obcaecati at eligendi voluptate tempore aspernatur. Maxime accusantium nobis ab, at voluptatem porro, fugit sed sint fugiat sapiente vel?</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="main-headings">
            <strong>PORTFOLIO</strong><i class="icon icon-angle-down"></i>
            <div class="main-blurb" id="blurb-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio similique aut voluptates, facilis, provident quae cupiditate dolore nisi non accusamus quidem dolorem dicta aliquam, quod temporibus. Quas deleniti, aliquam ab.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="main-headings">
            <strong>CONTACT</strong><i class="icon icon-angle-down"></i>
            <div class="main-blurb" id="blurb-4">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, recusandae. Commodi, mollitia autem necessitatibus dicta. Explicabo quam harum, perferendis repellat vel aut, est fugit assumenda blanditiis ratione, doloribus molestiae consequuntur.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

The effect I'm looking for is that, when one of the .icons is clicked, the .main-blurb below it is displayed, and all other .main-blurbs are hidden. Here's the js I've written:

```
$('section ul li .icon').click(function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('.main-blurb').hide();
    $('#blurb-' + (i+1)).show();
});
```

I've placed this in a .js file, and required it in my application.js. When I run this, nothing happens. I've restarted the server and all of that, and I'm just wondering if there is a bit of syntax I am missing.

Comment: you can also check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761234/sliding-text-from-under-image/41762646#41762646), it is similiar to yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was my ignorance of Javascript. I had forgotten to include:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

at the beginning of my javascript file. Everything works now!

Answer (score 2):

`var i = $(this).index();` is always equal to 1 because the `.icon` is the 2nd element in each `<li>`.

Try:

```
$('section ul li .icon').click(function() {
    $('.main-blurb').hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.main-blurb').show();
});
```

Comment: You can also use $(this).next('.main-blurb').show();

Comment: I've implemented this code, but still nothing happens when I click on the element. Is it possible that I'm loading the js incorrectly in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

whitout all your code is hard to know what is going on. 
to get next div below the tag `i` you can use jquery `next()` function:

```
$('section ul li .icon').click(function() {
    //hide all divs with main-blurb classes
    $('.main-blurb').hide();
    //show next element with main.blurb class
    $(this).next('.main-blurb').show();
});
```